# How to manage this has_many :through relationship in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

I have a type of data called a `chain`. Each `chain` is made up of a specific sequence of another type of data called a `step`. So a `chain` is ultimately made up of multiple `steps` in a specific order. I ultimately settled on the following tables:

```
TABLE chains
id   date_created

TABLE steps
id   description

TABLE chain_step_positions
chain_id   step_id   step_position
```

I'm unclear on how to manage the saving and retrieval of each chain's steps. I'm currently imagining the following:

**Saving**

1. The `chain_step_controller` would have an instance variable that is an array of the steps.
2. In the `create` method of the `chain_step_controller`, it would iterate over this array, instantiating and saving a new `ChainStepPosition` model.

**Retrieving**

Assuming I start with a `Chain`, I could do `chain.steps` to get an array of its steps. If this is right, would they be in the correct order (as specified by the `step_position` column in the table `chain_step_positions`)?

Answer (score 1):

As per Rohit Siddha's answer, I'd recommend using a [has_many :through association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) if you have two sets of data (`chain` and `step`):

---

**Models**

```
#app/models/chain.rb
Class Chain < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :step_positions
    has_many :steps, through: :step_positions
end

#app/models/step_position.rb
Class StepPosition < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :chain
    belongs_to :step
end

#app/models/step.rb
Class Step < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :step_positions
   has_many :steps, through: :step_positions
end
```

---

**Schemas**

```
chains
id | your | attributes | here | created_at | updated_at

step_positions
id | chain_id | step_id | your | attributes | created_at | updated_at

steps
id | your | attributes | here | created_at | updated_at
```

---

**Retrieval**

This will allow you to perform these queries in ActiveRecord:

```
@chain = Chain.find(params[:id])
@chain.steps == "step1 step2 step3 etc"
```

If you wanted to order the steps, I think you could use a `where` condition in the `has_many :through` association, like this:

```
#app/models/chain.rb
has_many :step_positions, -> { order(position: :asc) }
has_many :steps, through: :step_positions
```

Comment: How would the `step_position` data get saved in the first place?

Comment: Was going to write about this, but got distracted (sorry!). I'll write an answer in a few minutes for you!

Comment: Yes – this is what I was trying to suggest. Just couldn't remember the exact notation for `-> { order(position: :asc) }` thanks @RichPeck

Comment: @maxedison while you don't necessarily need a `step_positions` controller, you will still need to manually create the entries whenever you define an association via `StepPosition.new` this can be done in whichever controller you think makes the most sense

Comment: Ok, so I basically can't depend on as much Rails magic to manage this for me, correct?

Answer (score 0):

I believe `chain.steps` will be ordered by their primary key in the join (ie `chain_step_positions.id`).

You should be able to specify the sort order when you set up the relationship in your model, but I couldn't tell you how specifically without doing a bit of research first...

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this as given below :

```
class Chain < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :chain_step_positions
  has_many :steps, :through => :chain_step_positions
end

class Step < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :chain_step_positions
  has_many :chains, :through => :chain_step_positions
end

class ChainStepPosition < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :chain
  belongs_to :step
end
```

there is no need of `chain_step_controller`. You can use association methods to save record in chain_step_positions table

Comment: But how would the `step_position` data get saved?